# Get country name from ISO code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, iso

Having the list of country ISO codes, they are available [here](https://datahub.io/core/country-list) for reference:

Is there a way to return the country name from it?

Like, having a function, `getCountryName()`, which if called `getCountryName('AL')` will return 'Albania' and so on.

I was doing it as saving the whole list and work on it as with a dictionary but I was wondering if there is a method without saving the whole countries into a list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try [`Intl.DisplayNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DisplayNames/DisplayNames) of ECMAScript Internationalization API [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl):

```js
var getCountryNames = new Intl.DisplayNames(['en'], {type: 'region'});
console.log(getCountryNames.of('AL'));  // "Albania"
```

Answer (score 3):

Hei
you could use the JSON version of what you need, here https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/country-list/data_json/data/8c458f2d15d9f2119654b29ede6e45b8/data_json.json

then, with a forach, you loop over the file, with your ISO code, and when you find it, you ask your script to return the state name